# add resourse files to project with code

Tags: c#, reflection, resources

How could I archive this:

[image]

programmatically?

Is there a way of creating resource files with code?

Comment: Do I understand that you are _just_ looking for a way to create a file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't watch in resources but you can use resource.

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("Resources",FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(fs);
            writer.AddResource("TextFile1", "SomeText");
            writer.Generate();
            writer.Close();
```